# CentOS 6.5 installation

Tags: centos6

I have installed CentOS 6.5 today in one of the tower servers I have. Actually the screen went blank while installing and before I could select the options like Server/Desktop, the system automatically went ahead and I don't know which of the options is installed. I would like to change the settings to Basic Server. How should I do it?

I am **new** to servers and CentOS. Have some decent experience in Ubuntu though.

I haven't tried anything as I am not sure of the environment here.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform the selection during installation you're choosing a yum package group to install.  Yum package groups are similar to Ubuntu and Debian meta packages, like "build-essential" or "ubuntu-desktop". Package groups and meta packages install groups of packages.

Refer to the yum documentation, http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumGroups.

You'll want to use the `yum grouplist`, `yum groupremove` and `yum groupinstall` commands.